# Join two Joins?

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

Would it be possible to join the following two queries so that the tags for each audioid are included in the returned array?

```
SELECT audioposts.audioname, audioposts.userid, audioposts.audioid, users.gavatar, //users.name, users.email, audioposts.title, audioposts.likes, audioposts.userid FROM audioposts LEFT JOIN //users ON users.id = audioposts.userid

SELECT tagname FROM entitytag LEFT JOIN tags ON entitytag.tagid = tags.tagid WHERE entitytag.audioid = '$audioid'
```

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/1839439) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: Is this true even if I password protect my pages?

Comment: Joining these queries might be possible, but it's very unclear if this makes sense. You need to share more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want more `left join`s:

```
SELECT 
    ap.audioname, 
    ap.userid, 
    ap.audioid, 
    u.gavatar, 
    u.name, 
    u.email, 
    ap.title, 
    ap.likes, 
    ap.userid,
    t.tagname
FROM audioposts ap 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ap.userid
LEFT JOIN entitytag et on et.audioid = ap.audioid
LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid
```

I suspect that this would multiply the rows, since an `audiopost` probably might have several tags. You might be looking to gather all tag names together, for example using string aggregation. A correlated subquery would make sense for that:

```
SELECT 
    ap.audioname, 
    ap.userid, 
    ap.audioid, 
    u.gavatar, 
    u.name, 
    u.email, 
    ap.title, 
    ap.likes, 
    ap.userid,
    (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.tagname)
        FROM entitytag et
        LEFT JOIN tags t on t.tagid = et.tagid
        WHERE et.audioid = ap.audioid
    ) tagnames
FROM audioposts ap 
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = ap.userid
```

Comment: You are correct in that each audioid has three tags. So i tried your 2nd option but I'm guessing I've made an error. My PHP logs say; "Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object " . Will double check my code.

Comment: @Meggy: there was a typo in the subquery, `ad.audioid` had to be `ap.audioid`. You should learn to trap and report SQL errors in your PHP code - it makes debugging SQL errors *much* easier.